# What is this anime which started with a boy and his sister riding on a train to another dimension to search for their scientist parents?

Tags: final-fantasy

I watched this anime 10 years ago or more, and I missed the ending. During my childhood, this is one of my favorites.

The anime started with a little boy and his little sister riding a train at midnight to search for their lost parents. They met a girl in the train who rode the train to unlock the mystery of the train, and she also revealed that the train only appeared at midnight. The siblings told her they were in search of their parents who were scientist and was lost during the blast a year ago.

Their journey began when the train sent them into another dimension or world, where they met a man who possessed a gun with bullets of different type of effect (like fire, ice, water, air, etc.). Eventually, the man joined them in their search for the children's parent and sent them home too.

I guess that's a lot. Hope someone knows. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The anime is [**Final Fantasy: Unlimited**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy:_Unlimited). It was my favorite back then.

Synopsis from [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1157/Final_Fantasy:_Unlimited)

> Ai and Yu, after reading their parent's research and after their parents' disappearance, they decided to go on search for them. They ride a strange train to the Inner World in search of their parents and meets up with Lisa in the train and together they begin their journey within the Inner World.

Comment: omg! thank you so much @Ray. It's really is! i can't believe it is final fantasy unlimited all this time! Brings back the memory :) thank u for the answer

Comment: The pleasure is mine. And enjoy watching it! It is a good one!